# new operator is not allocating memory properly.

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

my code is suppose to create a singly linked list using and array of nodes.

each Node has variable item which hold data and variable next which holds the index of the next node in the list. the last node has -1 in its next data field to simulate a nullptr. head holds the index of the first node in the list.

for some reason when i try to create new memory the program throws an instance of bad_alloc

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>     what():  std::bad_alloc

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

ArrayList::ArrayList(char ch){
    array = new Node[Size];
    (array[0]).item = ch;
    (array[0]).next = 1;

    free = 1;
    head = 0;
  }

bool ArrayList::cons(char ch) {
    if (this->isFull()){
        this->doubleArray();
    }
    (array[free]).item = ch;
    (array[free]).next = head;
    head = free;
    free++;
   // cout << free << endl;
    return true;
}

bool ArrayList::isFull() const{
    int current = head;
    int count =0;
    while( (array[current]).next != -1 ){
        count++;
        current = (array[current]).next;
    }
    return (count == Size) ? true : false;
}

bool ArrayList::doubleArray() {
    int oldSize = Size;
    Size *=2;
    Node* newArray = new Node[Size]; // problem occurs here, i think

    int count =0;

    while(oldSize >= count ){
        (newArray[count]).item = (array[count]).item;
        (newArray[count]).next = (array[count]).next;
        count++;
    }
    free = count +1;
    delete [] array;
    array = newArray;
    cout <<"free: "<< free << endl;

    return true; // come up with thiss
}

void ArrayList::print() const{
    if (head == -1) return;
    int current = head;
    cout << "[ ";
    while( (array[current]).next != -1){
        cout << (array[current]).item <<" ";

        current = (array[current]).next;
    }
    cout << (array[current]).item <<"]";
    return;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H
#define ARRAYLIST_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class Node{
public:
    char item;
     int next;

    Node(){
        next = -1;
    }
    Node(char input){
        this->item = input;
        next = -1;
    }
};

class ArrayList{
public:
    ArrayList(char ch);
    int length() const;
    void print() const;

private:
     bool doubleArray();
    bool isFull() const;
    Node* array;
    int  Size = 5;
    int head = -1;
    int free = 0;
};
#endif
```

////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayList.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ArrayList list('1');
    list.cons('2');
    list.cons('3');
    list.cons('4');
    list.cons('5');
    list.cons('6');
    list.cons('7');
    list.print();

    //cout << list.length();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple new. Which one is the problem?

Comment: I do not think that the problem is with the "new". The problem is with your cons and isFull functions. cons functions, increases head by one. You start counting from head in isFull, since head is always increased by one, there is no way that count == Size.

Comment: Wrap each allocation in a try catch block to find the source of the exception. Also look at the requested size before allocating.

Comment: @deviantfan the one in double array

Comment: In double array you have an out of bounds access, since count will be equal to the old size in the last iteration.

Comment: You want to initialize Size, head and free in your constructor.  An uninitialized Size could explain why new object[Size] is failing.